# How to Call Web API From DotNet 3.5 Web Application with Object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-3.5

I have developed a Web API, I can access my api by using HttpClient in .NET 4 and 4.5  but I want to access this api from an existing .NET 3.5 application. Is it possible? I have learned from internet that HttpClient is not supported in .net 3.5, so how I consume this service in .net 3.5 application?

Comment: check out http://restsharp.org/

Comment: You can use WebRequest, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: WebAPI is the same as any other REST API. You can use whatever method you want to send an HTTP request, eg the built-in WebRequest class, any other library like RestSharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout this [link for .net version 3.5](http://www.thepicketts.org/2012/11/how-to-access-webapi-from-a-net-3-5-client-in-c/):

OR TRY THIS FOR 3.5

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient(); 
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json"; 
 client.BaseAddress = "ENDPOINT URL"; 
  string response = client.DownloadString(string.Format("{0}?{1}", Url, parameters.UrlEncode()));
```

This is how I am making call in .net 4.5.

```
var url = "YOUR_URL";
var client = new HttpClient();

var task = client.GetAsync(url);
return task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: you shouldn't use Result to read values from Task!
you should [await them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)!

Comment: @pikax: Thanks for the tip. Any reason why we should not use `Result()` to read the value?

Comment: @SharpCoder that's what `await` is for. By calling `Result` you are blocking the calling thread, losing any asynchronous benefit. If you can't use `await` you can use `ContinueWith` to keep working asynchronously. The only place where this is necessary though is in the `Main` method of Console programs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thanks for the explination. I will test my code. Currently I am using Result() & it seems to be working asynchronously. But I need to check.

Comment: It doesn't. Result blocks until the task finishes. There's no ambiguity here. You may receive a response from your local machine so fast you don't notice the delay, or you may be running the code block inside another Task.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
 // Create a request for the URL.       
 var request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");
 request.ContentType = contentType; //your contentType, Json, text,etc. -- or comment, for text
 request.Method = method; //method, GET, POST, etc -- or comment for GET
 using(WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse())
 {
    if(resp == null)
        new Exception("Response is null");

    return resp.GetResponseStream();//Get stream
}
```